Linearization of ODE flows on manifolds about arbitrary solutions
On Euclidean space, for an ODE
$$\dot x_t = F(x_t)$$
there is a natural linearization about $x_t$ given by
$$\dot y_t = y_t \cdot \nabla F(x_t).$$
On a manifold $M$, if we have a vector field $V$, we get the ODE flow
$$\dot x_t = V(x_t).$$
Intuitively, it seems like one should be able to describe the linearization of this ODE flow in a way that is independent of Riemannian metric, but we see in the Euclidean case that we have to differentiate the vector field $V$, which usually requires a connection. What is the correct intrinsic way to linearize an ODE flow given by a vector field on an arbitrary smooth manifold? Does it require a metric, and if so is the solution metric dependent?
This question is similar to this post, which concerns differentials of the flow map, which is of course very related to linearization of the ODE. The post did not receive a full answer though, and I take a different perspective here.

Throughout we fix a compact $d$-dimensional manifold without boundary, $M$, as well as a smooth vector field $V \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ on $M$. We do not a priori fix a Riemannian metric on $M$. The below discussion can be adapted to non-compact manifolds and to time dependent vector fields, but this introduces issues of the domain for which the flow map associated to the vector field is well defined that we don't take up here.
The vector field $V$ induces dynamics on the manifold, that is it induces an ODE that flows points on the manifold
$$\dot x_t = V(x_t).$$
Our goal is to understand the linearization of this flow about an arbitrary solution curve (not necessarily a stationary point for the vector field).
Linearization on $\mathbb{R}^d$
We recall that for ODE flows on Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^d$,
$$\dot x_t = F(x_t),$$
we can consider the linearization of this flow, which heuristically describes the evolution of a differential displacement in initial data to a differential displacement in the solution at time $t$. As this is a differential displacement, this map is linear, hence the name. Informally, the equation is derived as
$$\dot x_t + \dot{dy_t} = F(x_t + dy_t) = F(x_t) + dy_t \cdot \nabla F(x_t),$$
so that
$$\dot {dy_t} = \dot{dy_t} \cdot \nabla F(x_t).$$
More rigorously, we can introduce the flow map $\Phi_t : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$ which maps the initial value of the ODE to solutions at time $t$, $x_0 \mapsto x_t$. Then we note that $\Phi_t$ solves the ODE pointwise in $x$,
$$\dot \Phi_t = F\circ \Phi_t,$$
with $\Phi_0 = id$, the identity map on $\mathbb{R}^d$.
As stated above, the linearization of the flow sends differential displacements in initial values to differential displacements in solutions. This is then just given as the derivative of the flow map $\Phi_t$, that is the linearization of the dynamics about a curve $x_t$ with an initial displacement $y_0$ is given by
$$y_t = y_0 \cdot \nabla \Phi_t(x_0).$$
By differentiating the equation for $\Phi_t$, we see that
$$\dot \nabla \Phi_t = \nabla \Phi_t \nabla F(\Phi_t),$$
with implicit matrix multiplication. Plugging in then $x_0$ and dotting both sides with $y_0$, we get
$$\dot y_t = y_t \cdot \nabla F(x_t),$$
which is then just the heuristically derived equation above.
Definining the linearization on $M$
With an understanding of the linearization of dynamics on $\mathbb{R}^d$ in hand, we wish to understand how to linearize the dynamics on the manifold $M$ induced by the vector field $V$. In this setting, we also introduce the flow map $\Phi_t : M \to M$, which for each time is a diffeomorphism of $M$ sending initial values to solutions to the ODE flow, $x_0 \mapsto x_t$. $\Phi_t$ then pointwise in $x \in M$ solves the ODE
$$\dot \Phi_t = V \circ \Phi_t,$$
with $\Phi_0  = id$, the identity map on $M$.
In Euclidean space, the differential displacement $y_t$ was just a vector in $\mathbb{R}^d$ solving a linear equation. On $M$, $y_t$ becomes a tangent vector. $y_t$ is the differential displacement in the solution generated by taking a differential displacement $y_0$ in the initial value of the ODE flow. Analogously to above, this is formalized using the differential of the flow map,
$$y_t := T\Phi_t(x_0,y_0),$$
where $T\Phi_t : TM \to TM$ is the differential of $\Phi$ (sometimes denoted $D\Phi_t$ or $d\Phi_t$).
We note that $y_t$ is defined intrinsically (that is coordinate-independent) and in a geometry independent way, that is $y_t$ depends only on the smooth structure on $M$ and does not depend on a choice of Riemannian metric.
An equation for linearization in coordinates
Our goal now to derive an ODE for $y_t$, analogous to the one written above. The most straightforward thing to do is to just expand the definition of $y_t$ using coordinates and mimic the derivation in Euclidean space from above. Writing the equation for $\Phi_t$ in coordinates, we get
$$\dot \Phi_t^k(x_0) = V^k(\Phi_t(x_0)).$$
We then apply $y_0^j \partial_j$ to both sides and get
$$\frac{d}{dt} (y_0^j \partial_j \Phi_t^k(x_0)) = y_0^j \partial_j \Phi^\ell_t(x_0) \partial_\ell V^k(\Phi_t(x_0)).$$
Then writing the definition of $y_t$ in coordinates
$$y_t^k = y_0^j \partial_j \Phi_t^k(x_0),$$
so the above equation simplifies to
$$\dot y_t^k = y_t^\ell \partial_\ell V^k(x_t).$$
Thus in any coordinates, we get an equation for $y_t$, which is notably identical to the equation for the linearization in Euclidean space.
Linearization using a Riemannian metric
This works as a way of computing linearizations in coordinates but is annoyingly not manifestly intrinsic, that is we haven't succeeded in writing down an equation for the tangent vector $y_t$ with purely intrinsic quantities.
As a first pass at writing a more "geometric" equation for the linearization, we will work with a Riemannian metric. We note that the quantity we are trying to compute is metric independent; despite this, it turns any metric compatible with the smooth structure will give rise to a convenient equation for the tangent vector $y_t.$ Let $g$ be a Riemannian metric on $M$ and $\nabla$ be the Levi-Civita connection associated to $g$. Recall that $\nabla$ induces a covariant derivative on curves $\gamma : \mathbb{R} \to TM$, $\frac{D\gamma}{dt} : \mathbb{R} \to TM$ (as in O'Neill Semi-Riemannian Geometry, 3.18). Using the connection and the induced covariant derivative, we can write down a natural candidate equation for $y_t$ by taking the equation on Euclidean space and replacing all Euclidean derivatives with their covariant counterparts. This equation is then
$$\frac{D}{dt} y_t = \nabla_{y_t} V(x_t).$$
We note that this is equality of elements of the tangent bundle $TV$ and that both the left and right hand sides are connection dependent. We now wish to verify that this equation is in fact true. For this to be the case, we need the connection dependent part of each side of the equation to cancel, as $y_t$ is independent of the connection. This is in fact what happens, which become clear by writing both expressions in coordinates. Expanding each side using the Christoffel symbol $\Gamma^k_{ij}$, we get
$$\dot y^k_t + \Gamma^k_{ij} \dot x_t^i y_t^j =y_t^i \Big(\partial_i V^k(x_t) + \Gamma^k_{ij} V^j(x_t) \Big).$$
Using then that $\dot x^i_t = V^i(x_t)$ and that $\Gamma^k_{ij} = \Gamma^k_{ji}$, we see that the terms involving the Christoffel symbol exactly cancel, leaving
$$\dot y^k_t = y^i_t \partial_i V^k(x_t),$$
which is exactly the expression for $y_t$ derived above. Thus we have a found a simple equation for $y_t$ using the covariant derivative, despite $y_t$ being independent of choice of metric. We have thus gotten closer to the goal of an intrinsic equation for $y_t$ but fallen short as this equation requires superfluous structure. Nonetheless, it is nice to see that the natural guess for a covariant version of the linearization equation is in fact true, regardless of underlying metric.
The double tangent bundle, the canonical flip, and the canonical lift
We want to write an intrinsic ODE for $y_t$, which is a curve in $TM$. In order to write an intrinsic ODE for a curve $z_t$ in $M$, we need a vector field $W \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$, that is $W : M \to TM$ where $\pi_{TM} \circ W(x)  = x$ ($\pi_{TM} : TM \to M$ is the natural projection map). Thus what we need is a vector field $L : TM \to TTM$ for which
$$\dot y_t = L(y_t).$$
$L$ should be built out of $V$ and further, since $\pi_{TM} \circ y_t = x_t$, we have
$$V(\pi_{TM} \circ y_t) = V(x_t) = \dot x_t = T x(t,e_1)= T( \pi_{TM} \circ y)(t,e_1) = T\pi_{TM} \circ Ty(t,e_1) = T\pi_{TM} \circ L(y_t),$$
where $e_1 \in T_t \mathbb{R}$ is the natural unit vector. A seemingly natural guess for $L$ should be is given by the differential of $V$, as $TV : TM \to TTM$. Let $\pi_{TTM} : TTM \to TM$ be the natural projection map. Then for $TV$ to be a vector field on $TM$, we need $\pi_{TTM} \circ TV(y) = y$. But by the definition of the differential $\pi_{TTM} \circ TV(y) = V(\pi_{TM} \circ y) = V(x)$. Thus $TV$ is not generically a vector field on $TM$. On the other hand, we note that
$$T \pi_{TM} \circ TV = T(\pi_{TM} \circ V) = T (Id_M) = Id_{TM}.$$
The above computations show that we want $L : TM \to TTM$ to have the properties
$$\pi_{TTM} \circ L = Id_{TM} \quad \text{and} \quad T\pi_{TM} \circ L = V \circ \pi_{TM}$$
and that $TV$ has the properties
$$T\pi_{TM} \circ TV = Id_{TM} \quad \text{and} \quad \pi_{TTM} \circ TV = V \circ \pi_{TM}.$$
Thus $TV$ is acting like $L$, but with $T\pi_{TM}$ and $\pi_{TTM}$ switched. This has to do with the fact that $TTM$ has two natural vector bundle structures over $TM$: one as the tangent space of $TM$ given by the projection $\pi_{TTM}$ and one as the derivative of the vector bundle $(TM, \pi_{TM}, M)$ given by the projection $T\pi_{TM}$. The former vector bundle structure is specific to the double tangent bundle while the latter, also referred to as the secondary bundle structure, is a natural structure on the tangent space of an vector bundle. It turns out these two vector bundles are natural isomorphic by an involution $\kappa_{TTM} : TTM \to TTM$ known as the canonical flip. Specifically $\kappa_{TTM}$ is a diffeomorphism such that
$$\kappa_{TTM} \circ \kappa_{TTM} = Id_{TTM}, \quad \pi_{TTM} \circ \kappa_{TTM} = T\pi_{TM},\quad T\pi_{TM} \circ \kappa_{TTM} = \pi_{TTM}.$$
We can write $\kappa_{TTM}$ in coordinates $\phi : M \supseteq U \to V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ as follows
$$T^2 \phi \circ \kappa_{TTM} \circ T^2 \phi^{-1}(x,y,u,v) = \kappa_{\mathbb{R}^{4d}}(x,y,u,v) := (x,u,y,v).$$
That is $\kappa_{TTM}$ flips the middle two coordinates of the element of $TTM$. We now verify that $\kappa_{TTM}$ is defined independent of coordinates. Letting $\psi : U \to W\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ be another coordinate chart, we have
$$T^2\psi \circ \kappa_{TTM} \circ T^2 \psi^{-1} = T^2(\psi \circ \phi^{-1}) \circ T^2 \phi \circ \kappa_{TTM} \circ T^2 \phi^{-1} \circ T^2( (\psi \circ \phi^{-1})^{-1}) =T^2(\psi \circ \phi^{-1}) \circ\kappa_{\mathbb{R}^{4d}} \circ T^2( (\psi \circ \phi^{-1})^{-1}),$$
so it suffices to see for a diffeomorphism $\gamma : \mathbb{R}^d \supseteq V \to W \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{d}$ that
$$T^2 \gamma \circ \kappa_{\mathbb{R}^{4d}} \circ T^2 \gamma^{-1} = \kappa_{\mathbb{R}^{4d}},$$
which we compute directly
\begin{align*}T^2 \gamma \circ& \kappa_{\mathbb{R}^{4d}} \circ T^2 \gamma^{-1}(x,y,u,v) 
\\&= T^2 \gamma \circ \kappa_{\mathbb{R}^{4d}}(\gamma^{-1}(x), y \cdot \nabla \gamma^{-1}(x), u \cdot \nabla \gamma^{-1}(x), u \otimes y : \nabla^2 \gamma^{-1}(x) + v \cdot\nabla \gamma^{-1}(x))
\\&= T^2 \gamma (\gamma^{-1}(x), u \cdot \nabla \gamma^{-1}(x), y \cdot \nabla \gamma^{-1}(x),  u \otimes y : \nabla^2 \gamma^{-1}(x) + v \cdot\nabla \gamma^{-1}(x))
\\&=  (x, (u \cdot \nabla \gamma^{-1}(x)) \cdot \nabla \gamma(\gamma^{-1} (x)), (y \cdot \nabla \gamma^{-1}(x))\cdot \nabla \gamma(\gamma^{-1}(x)), z)
\\&= (x, u, y, z)
\end{align*}
where we use that $I = \nabla( \gamma \circ \gamma^{-1}) = \nabla \gamma^{-1} (\nabla \gamma) \circ \gamma^{-1},$ and
\begin{align*}
    z &:=(y \cdot \nabla \gamma^{-1}(x)) \otimes (u \cdot \nabla \gamma^{-1}(x)): \nabla^2 \gamma(\gamma^{-1}(x)) + (u \otimes y) : \nabla^2 \gamma^{-1}(x) \cdot \nabla \gamma(\gamma^{-1}(x))
    \\&\qquad\qquad + (v \cdot \gamma^{-1}(x)) \cdot \nabla \gamma(\gamma^{-1}(x))
    \\&= (u \otimes v) : \nabla^2 (\gamma \circ \gamma^{-1}) + v
    \\&= v.
\end{align*}
Thus we have shown that
$$T^2 \gamma \circ \kappa_{\mathbb{R}^{4d}} \circ T^2 \gamma^{-1}(x,y,u,v) = (x,u,y,v) = \kappa_{\mathbb{R}^{4d}}(x,y,u,v),$$
which shows that $\kappa_{TTM}$ is well defined independent of coordinates.
We now verify the claimed properties of $\kappa_{TTM}$. The involution property $\kappa_{TTM} \circ \kappa_{TTM} = Id_{TTM}$ is clear from the coordinate definition. We show now that $\pi_{TTM} \circ \kappa_{TTM} = T\pi_{TM}$; the other property follows from applying $\kappa_{TTM}$ to both sides of this identity.
In coordinates,
$$\pi_{TTM} \circ \kappa_{TTM}(x,y,u,v) = \pi_{TTM}(x,u,y,v) = (x,u),$$
while
$$T\pi_{TM}(x,y,u,v) = (\pi_{TM}(x,y), (u,v) \cdot \nabla (\pi_{TM}(x,y))) = (x, u \cdot \nabla_x x) = (x,u),$$
thus giving us the desired equality.
Thus with the properties of $\kappa_{TTM}$ established, we see that
$$L := \kappa_{TTM} \circ TV$$
has the desired properties of the linearization vector field, in particular $\kappa_{TTM} \circ TV \in \mathfrak{X}(TM)$ as
$$\pi_{TTM} \circ \kappa_{TTM} \circ TV = T\pi_{TM} \circ TV = Id_{TM}.$$
We note in particular that for any vector field $V, \kappa_{TTM} \circ TV$ is a vector field on $TM$, thus is a natural lifting of a vector field to a vector field on the tangent bundle. This is sometimes called the canonical lift of $V$.
The intrinsic linearized equation
Thus we get an intrinsic (in the sense now that it requires only constructions involving purely the smooth structure and so is manifestly independent of coordinates and metric) ODE flow on $TV$, given by
$$\dot y_t = \kappa_{TTM} \circ TV(y_t).$$
We now verify that $y_t$ as defined above in fact solves this equation. Again, we write the expression in coordinates, yielding
$$\frac{d}{dt} (x_t^1,...,x_t^d,y_t^1,...,y_t^d) = (V^1(x_t),...,V^d(x_t), y_t^j \partial_j V^1(x_t),..., y_t^j \partial_j V^d(x_t)).$$
We see then that equation says
$$\dot x_t^k = V^k(x_t) \quad \text{and}\quad \dot y_t^k = y_t^j \partial_j V^k(x_t),$$
which is exactly the equations we already have shown $x_t, y_t$ solve in coordinates. Thus $y_t$ really does solve the above intrinsic equation.
Summary
For an ODE flow
$$\dot x_t = V(x_t)$$
on a manifold $M$ we see there are three equivalent equations for the linearization about $x_t$, the curve in the tangent bundle given by $y_t = T\Phi_t(x_0,y_0)$. One is the ODE in coordinates
$$\dot y_t^k = y_t^j \partial_j V^k(x_t).$$
The next is for any Riemannian metric and Levi-Cevita connection $\nabla$,
$$\frac{D}{dt} y_t = \nabla_{y_t} V(x_t),$$
where $\frac{D}{dt}$ is the induced covariant derivative. The final is the intrinsic equation that doesn't require coordinates or a connection,
$$\dot y_t = \kappa_{TTM} \circ TV(y_t),$$
where $\kappa_{TTM}: TTM \to TTM$ is the "canonical flip", defined in coordinates as
$$\kappa(x,y,u,v) = (x,u,y,v).$$
Since for all these equations, we have unique solutions for given initial data, we have that $y_t = T\Phi_t(x_0,y_0)$ iff $y_t$ solves any one of these equation iff $y_t$ solves all the above equations. In particular, we see that the first two equations, while not manifestly invariant under coordinate transformations and changes of metric, they are in fact invariant.

Why do you ask a question an at the same time (7:18 pm) answer it?

@SampleTime Couldn't find an answer to this question so figure it out on my own. Decided to post here for others to reference, as is generally encouraged.

Yes, answering your own question is fine. To me it was just unclear if you actually have a question (i.e. your answer is just an attempt) or not. Would be great to point it out clearly and directly in the main question that the question is already solved, so that people that are looking for unsolved problems don't waste their time.
